# How to mux two x-rtp streams using gstreamer?

Tags: udp, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I want to stream audio and video through the same port using udpsink. Is this possible?

I tried this pipeline :

```
gst-launch \

rtpmux name=mux ! udpsink clients=[client IP]:[client port] sync=false async=false -v \

videotestsrc ! ffenc_h264 ! rtph264pay ! mux.sink_0 \

audiotestsrc is-live=true ! mad ! rtpmpapay ! mux.sink_1
```

But its not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[RTPMUX](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpmux.html) only works if the two streams have the EXACT SAME Clock rate. `rtph264pay` pass off a clock rate of at least `90000`, which I can almost guarantee that your audio stream does not match.